# Need help with formulating a JPA query, please

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Given these two entities in a database accessed through Hibernate JPA,

```
@Entity class A {
   int id;
   String aName;
}

@Entity class B {
   int id;
   String bName;
   @ManyToMany Set<A> aRefs;
}
```

the result I want is the collection of the `aName`s of all A entities that are *not* referred to by B entities. Or in other words, all `A`s which are not part of any `B`'s `aRefs`.

I've tried a number of alternatives using `NOT EXISTS` and `NOT MEMBER OF` with subselects and even dabbled with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s, but annoyingly enough the queries I come up with either get rejected by Hibernate's interpreter or even end up translated to invalid SQL that's rejected by Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 people showed interest in this question, so I thought I'd share my answer. I arrived at this mostly by trial and error; I'm sorry to say I still don't "grok" the JPA Query Language.

2 queries that work are:

```
SELECT a FROM A a WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT b FROM B b JOIN b.arefs ba WHERE a = ba)
```

and

```
SELECT a FROM A a WHERE a NOT IN 
    (SELECT ba FROM B b JOIN b.arefs ba)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is from the top of my head - so I'm not sure if this will work or be a correct solution for you.

Add the other side of your relationship in entity A

```
@Entity class A {
   int id;
   String aName;
   @ManyToOne B bref;
}
```

then you can create a ejb-ql statment to says something like "SELECT a FROM A a WHERE a.b is NULL"

Comment: Hmm. I'm gonna set up a little test harness to try these suggestions. I'm in a work environment with a productive database here, so I'm *very* hesitant to mess with the data structure. But I'll try that if nothing else works. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you will need to change your underlying data structure. If you add the reference from entity A to B (the manyToOne ref) , you can set the loading to lazy to make sure that you're not pulling to much data from the database. you can also set extra attributes in the @ManyToOne annotation to specify which columns define the relationship between entity A & B. The [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html) shows a nice example of this bi-directional relationship

Comment: Do you even have to change the data structure? The current @OneToMany surely must be stored somewhere, be it in a A.B_ID column or in a B_A_REFS intermediate table. Can't you design a @ManyToOne field in A that makes use of the existing database structure?

Comment: Your suggestion is probably good but because I'm not very good with JPA I'm very hesitant to change the entity definitions. My priority was to write a query that made use of the existing, unmodified structure. I've meanwhile puzzled out an answer (see my answer). Still, thanks for your help!

Comment: @wallenborn: Please see my comment to ChristiaanP!